# Too many input arguments when reading excel sheet into matlab plot

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, input

I am having trouble with plotting excel data in matlab.

My excel sheet is rather big, but I only want to plot the columns A(3:301), R(3:301) and Q(3:301).
I get an "too many input arguments" error with the following code.

I dont really know how to tell matlab this, can somebody please help?

I get this error:
Warning: Column headers from the file were modified to make them valid
MATLAB identifiers before creating variable names for the table. The
original column headers are saved in the VariableDescriptions property.
Set 'PreserveVariableNames' to true to use the original column headers
as table variable names.
Error using tabular/plot
Too many input arguments.

Error in DataresultsPlot (line 27)
plot(time_data, T_proximal, current_data);

```
% Pfade zu den Ordnern mit den Excel-Dateien angeben
folder_paths = {
    'C:\Users\anhky\Documents\Uni Stuff\Master\Masterarbeit\Evaluation\Data\d_2mm\Experiment 1',
    
};

% Loop über alle Ordner
for folder_index = 1:length(folder_paths)
    folder_path = folder_paths{folder_index};
    
    % Dateien in dem Ordner auflisten
    file_list = dir(fullfile(folder_path, '*.xlsx'));
    
    % Loop über alle Dateien in dem Ordner
    for file_index = 1:length(file_list)
        % Excel-Datei einlesen
        file_path = fullfile(folder_path, file_list(file_index).name);
        data = readtable(file_path);
        
        % x- und y-Daten extrahieren
        time_data = data(3:end, 1); % erste Spalte in Excel
        T_proximal = data(3:end, 18); % zweite Spalte in Excel
        current_data = data(3:end, 17); % dritte Spalte in Excel
        
        % Graphen plotten
        figure; % neues Figure-Fenster öffnen
        plot(time_data, T_proximal, current_data);
        
        % Achsenbeschriftungen hinzufügen
        xlabel('time');
        ylabel('T proximal');
        zlabel('current');

        
        % Titel hinzufügen
        title(file_list(file_index).name);
        
        % Graphen als PNG-Datei speichern
        save_path = fullfile('C:\Pfad\zum\Speicherort', [file_list(file_index).name '.png']);
        saveas(gcf, save_path);
    end
end
```

Comment: See the [documentation of plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#d124e1109144). To plot multiple lines, you need to either combine your Y’s into a single matrix or pair each one with its own X.

Comment: The error occurs in the line `plot(time_data, T_proximal, current_data)`. The error message tells you so. Then you read the docs for `plot` to learn why it gives the error message. Turns out `plot` takes two array arguments, you pass it three. So, what are you trying to do with that statement? What do you want to plot and how do you want the plot to look like?

Answer (score 0):

as per the warning, don't worry about it, it's just that it doesn't like how you formatted the text in you columns header (i.e. there is a ' '), docs:

> Read the tabular data back using readtable. By default, MATLAB® converts any variable names that include spaces and non-ASCII characters into valid MATLAB® identifiers. For example, MATLAB® converts the variable names 'Last Name' to 'LastName', and 'Smoker (1 or 0)' to 'Smoker_1or0_'. To read the tabular data while preserving variable names, set the 'VariableNamingRule' parameter to preserve.

. You could either reformat the header or do as the warning says, so:

```
data = readtable(file_path, "VariableNamingRule","preserve");
```

as per the plot, try this if you want to plot the data in the same figure:

```
figure;
plot(time_data, T_proximal);
hold on;
plot(T_proximal, current_data);
```

or, as i see that you try to label 3 axis, if you want a 3d plot:

```
plot3(time_data, T_proximal, current_data);
```